# How do you integrate this new Spark libary for python?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am using spark with python using the pyspark command.

I came across this new library

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

which I want to integrate into my spark program written in python.

I have downloaded the complete codebase shown in the above link but not sure how to proceed from there. Should I just copy its contents somewhere?

Any guidance would help as I am still learning scala and spark and want to use the above library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to repeat information from [the `README` file](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/README.md). To use `spark-csv` in your script you should use `--packages` option for each execution of `spark-submit` or `pyspark` shell.